# R Markdown multiple plots in a single chunk only works intermittently

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

R *code chunk #1* correctly plots 'cars' and 'pressure'. I'd expect *code chunk #2* to behave similarly and plot 'pressure' twice. It doesn't. Why?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Text

```{r code chunk 1, echo=FALSE, fig.width=6, fig.asp=0.618, out.width="50%", fig.align="default"}
plot(cars)
plot(pressure)
```

Text

```{r code chunk 2, echo=FALSE, fig.width=6, fig.asp=0.618, out.width="50%", fig.align="default"}
plot(pressure)
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image: intermittent r markdown multiple plots]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, **knitr** discards consecutive identical plots in the same code chunk. If you want to keep all of them, you may use the chunk option `fig.keep = 'all'`, e.g.,

````
```{r code chunk 2, fig.keep='all'}
plot(pressure)
plot(pressure)
```
````

As for the reason, see the (old) manual https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/manual/ (Section 3.2). In short, **knitr** captures a snapshot of the current graphical device after evaluating each expression in a code chunk (no matter if the expression has anything to do with plotting), and see if there are any changes in the snapshot. If the snapshot remains identical to the previous version, it assumes that no new plot was produced. You can force **knitr** to keep all plots, even if they are identical to each other, by `fig.keep = 'all'`.